# How to create an Alias in Apache to a network shared directory?

Tags: apache, osx-mavericks, file-permissions, nas

I'm running Apache 2.2 (on OS 10.9 Mavericks) and have a directory on my NAS (My Cloud EX2100) that I would like to set up with as an aliased web site.

To do so, I've created a .conf file (I called it aliases.conf) in `/private/etc/apache2/other` (Note that the httpd.conf has `Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf` added to it).

In my `aliases.conf` I have

```
Alias /foo /Volumes/bar/
<Directory "/Volumes/bar">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I then restart apache and open a browser to go to `http://localhost/foo`, but I get the error message

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /foo on this server.

How do I give Apache access to the shared/aliased directory that is on the NAS?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the apache user has read permissions to your NAS folder.
Furthermore switch the order of allow and deny to `Order deny,allow`

I don't know if you have any index files. But if you would like to browse through your directories you have to modify your options entry to: `Options FollowSymLinks Idexes`

Then restart your apache and try again.